# Чому дієслово "клясти" має два настільки різних значення?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, етимологія, омоніми

Слово *клясти(-ся)* має два дуже різні значення:

1. [*клясти*](http://sum.in.ua/s/kljasty) — проклинати, лаяти, бажати зла;
2. [*клястися*](http://sum.in.ua/s/kljastysja) — обіцяти комусь щось, присягати на вірність; також *клятва*.

Що обумовило подібну різницю значень, здавалося б, одного дієслова?

Answer (score 6):

[Макс Фасмер](//vasmer.lexicography.online/%D0%BA/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83):

> Значення «клястися» виникло з «проклинати себе».

Поки що не дуже зрозуміло.

---

Розглянемо таке слово як «[заклинати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaklynaty)». Воно має декілька значень, серед яких первісним я вважаю наступне:

> **1.** *перех.* Промовляючи магічні заклинання, діяти на кого-, що-небудь, підкоряти своїй волі

Інші вже, на мою думку, походять від нього:

- «**2.** *перех.* Те саме, що проклинати.» — тобто промовляти щодо людини магічні заклинання / діяти на неї таким чином, щоби людині стало погано.
- «**3.** *тільки недок., перех., перен.* Настійно прохати, благати про що-небудь.» — тобто промовляти щодо людини майже магічні заклинання / діяти на неї словом таким чином, щоби вона зголосилася зробити по-твоєму (або, як варіант: щоби накликати на неї щастя чи біду в залежності від того, чи зголоситься вона чи ні).
- «**4.** *тільки док., неперех., діал.* Вилаятися.» — послаблене значення 2.

Звідси очевидно походження «[заклинатися](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaklynatysja)» («**1.** Те саме, що присягатися. / *тільки док., на що.* Поклястися чим-небудь зробити щось. **2.** *тільки док., з інфін.* Давши зарік, перестати, кинути що-небудь робити; заректися.»): початкове значення цього слова — промовляти до себе магічні заклинання / діяти на себе таким чином, щоби змусити себе виконати щось, не відійти від наміченого, не зламатися/засумніватися (заклинати себе).

Потім значення слова природно розширилося — заклинатися стали не лише в моменти сумнівів задля певної дії на себе, а й щоб переконати інших у своїй рішучості зробити щось (мовляв: «як мені можна не вірити, якщо я *заклинаю* себе?»). Хоча й зараз релігійні люди кажуть «клястися не можна — це гріх»  (чому не можна, адже навіть святі давали [обітницю](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F), тобто в самому факті обіцянки нічого поганого немає? а тому що клятва за своїм початковим значенням — це саме магічна дії, а не просто обіцянка).

---

Щодо «клястися» (фактичний синонім «заклинатися»):

1. Або «клястися» походить не від «клясти себе», а є скороченням «заклинатися» («заклинати себе»).
2. Або, що ймовірніше, раніше «клясти» мало увесь спектр значень слова «заклинати» (а не лише 2-е і 4-е, як зараз), але потім малопотрібні значення вивітрилися. Відповідно, «клястися» походить від «клясти [зникле 1-е значення] себе» — так само, як і «заклинатися» від «заклинати себе», і як стверджує Фасмер.

Comment: Цікаво. А який зв'язок із «клясти» у значенні «лаяти»? І ще, не дуже зрозуміло, яким чином `-клят-` і `-клин-` є спорідненими.

Comment: @bytebuster: (1) Див. «заклинати 4». (2) Див. статтю Фасмера.